# Is there a way to (re-save) an image (that already exists locally) with javascript, "without opening the image in the tab"?

Tags: javascript, html, filesaver.js

I have an anchor tag that refers to an image that already exists on my local machine,

What I want is, when the user clicks on it, it downloads the image (and not open it in a tab)

The current behavior is, when I click on it, it opens the image in the browser in the same tab (or a new tab if target="_blank")

I understand that the file already exists, but I want to 're-save' it again.

I noticed the following behavior when I used this anchor tag:

`<a title="title" href="localpath/image.jpg" download></a>`

- Firefox: downloads(save) the image correctly.
- Edge: opens the image in the tab.
- Chrome: sometimes behaves like Firefox and sometimes like Edge, (happens randomly on different machines).

I tried [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) but didn't work as I want.

I know that there has to be a server for the "download" attribute to work, but I guess there's something I'm missing.

Note: my html works on static files, it never fetches a server. and I updated my browsers to the latest versions, and cleared my cache and cookies :)